# Creating nested structures using Linq throws error

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I want to execute a query that creates a hierarchical set of structures. The query looks like

```
public class PrimaveraWBS
{
    public int PrimaveraId { get; set; }
    public int InternalId { get; set; }
    public int ContainerId { get; set; }

    public string ContainerName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PrimaveraWBS> Children { get; set; }
}

var wbscodes = (from o in Projects
                where o.Id == id
                from p in o.ProjectDisciplines
                select new PrimaveraWBS
                {
                    ContainerName = p.Discipline.Name,
                    ContainerId = p.Id,
                    PrimaveraId = 0,
                    Children = (from q in CheckLists
                        where q.Assessment_Id == lastAssessmentId && q.Discipline.Id == p.Discipline_Id
                        select new PrimaveraWBS
                        {
                            ContainerName = q.Name,
                            ContainerId = q.Id,
                            PrimaveraId = 0,
                            Children = (from r in q.Groups
                                select new PrimaveraWBS
                                {
                                    ContainerName = r.Name,
                                    ContainerId = r.Id,
                                    PrimaveraId = 0,
                                }).ToList()
                        }).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

when I execute the code I get the following error, which is very descriptive, however, I cant seem to initialize the last 'Children' element to a null list for the life of me.

> NotSupportedException: The type 'STOrm.Utility.PrimaveraWBS' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.

How can I terminate the hierarchy at the bottom so linq does not complain?

Comment: Just FYI all of the ToLists() are there because I was trying different things.  They normally will not be in the query.

Comment: I haven't encountered that, but have you tried explicitly setting `Children = null` in the innermost `PrimaveraWBS` property initializer?

Comment: yes I have and that does not work it throws a different error.  It is very strange this seems like such an easy requirement